# Regex to find all text outside square brackets

Tags: python, regex

**This is my script:**

```
import re

corpus = "Me[Unknown] temo[Unknown] que[Unknown] buscare[Unknown] otras[Unknown] opciones[Unknown] esta[Unknown] nunca[ADV+NEG+H_CIRCONSTANT_TEMPS+C_TPS_FREQUENCE+SC_FREQUENCE_FORTE] 
más[ADV+comp+PADV+H_CIRCONSTANT_QUANTITE+C_QNT_FORTE] compraré[V+H_PREDICAT_ACTION+C_PREDICAT_TRANSACTION+SC_TRANSACTION_ACHAT] buscare[INCONNU] otras[INCONNU] opciones[INCONNU] por[INCONNU] la[INCONNU] calidad[INCONNU] de[INCONNU] la[INCONNU] luz[INCONNU]"

regex = re.findall(r"(\w+)\[ADV\+NEG\+H_CIRCONSTANT_TEMPS.*?\]/(\w+)\[ADV\+comp\+PADV\+H_CIRCONSTANT_QUANTITE.*?\]/(\w+)\[V+H_PREDICAT_ACTION+C_PREDICAT_TRANSACTION.*?\]", texte)

print(regex)
```

**I need these outputs:**

> nunca más compraré

and

> nunca[ADV+NEG+H_CIRCONSTANT_TEMPS+C_TPS_FREQUENCE+SC_FREQUENCE_FORTE] más[ADV+comp+PADV+H_CIRCONSTANT_QUANTITE+C_QNT_FORTE] compraré[V+H_PREDICAT_ACTION+C_PREDICAT_TRANSACTION+SC_TRANSACTION_ACHAT]

**Output:**

> []

Comment: regex is to match pattern and what pattern you seek here?

Comment: I search the sequence: "nunca más compraré"

Comment: I'm so sorry RomanPerekhrest. I have many difficulties in regex and when I have an answer here, I try to understand it and then redo it myself. I'm not here to spam, but I'm not here just to copy responses. I'm very happy to see people with so much knowledge around here. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

text = "Me[Unknown] temo[Unknown] que[Unknown] buscare[Unknown] otras[Unknown] opciones[Unknown] esta[Unknown] nunca[ADV+NEG+H_CIRCONSTANT_TEMPS+C_TPS_FREQUENCE+SC_FREQUENCE_FORTE]más[ADV+comp+PADV+H_CIRCONSTANT_QUANTITE+C_QNT_FORTE] compraré[V+H_PREDICAT_ACTION+C_PREDICAT_TRANSACTION+SC_TRANSACTION_ACHAT] buscare[INCONNU] otras[INCONNU] opciones[INCONNU] por[INCONNU] la[INCONNU] calidad[INCONNU] de[INCONNU] la[INCONNU] luz[INCONNU]"

regex = re.findall(r"([A-Za-z\[\] ]+)\] (\w+)\[ADV\+NEG\+H_CIRCONSTANT_TEMPS.*?\](\w+)\[ADV\+comp\+PADV\+H_CIRCONSTANT_QUANTITE.*?\](?: )(\w+)\[V\+H_PREDICAT_ACTION\+C_PREDICAT_TRANSACTION.*?\]", text)

print(' '.join(regex[0][1:]))
```

I just corrected few mistakes in your regex:

1. You have used `(\w+)` to match characters before `nunca` but \w don't match `[` or `]` so I used `([A-Za-z\[\] ]+)\]` instead which matches alphabets, braces and spaces
2. you have used `/(\w+)` where `\w+` to match your word but `/` before `(\w+)` is unnecessary which won't find your desire result
3. Finally you forgot to use escape characters at last match where you have used `[V+H_PREDICAT_ACTION+C_PREDICAT_TRANSACTION.*?\]` so I used `\+` instead of `+` to escape the character `+`.

So applying the fix you will get result:

```
nunca más compraré
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `re.findall` and `str.join`

```
In [48]: ' '.join(re.findall('[^\s\]]+(?=\[)', text))
Out[48]: 'nunca más compraré'
```

---

**Details**

- `[^\s\]]+` - match anything that is not a whitespace char or closing brace
- `(?=\[)` - lookahead for an opening `[`

Comment: are you sure about your regex? I got `'Me temo que buscare otras opciones esta nunca[ADV+NEG+H_CIRCONSTANT_TEMPS+C_TPS_FREQUENCE+SC_FREQUENCE_FORTE]más compraré buscare otras opciones por la calidad de la luz'` which is none of the require result

Comment: @Gahan I thought there was something missing. Fixed it now. Also, your regex is unnecessarily complex.

Comment: I just corrected him, nothing else, couldn't tell that long in comment.and still your output is `'Me temo que buscare otras opciones esta nunca más compraré buscare otras opciones por la calidad de la luz'`